# How to handle LdapConnection timeout in case of offline server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, openldap

I am working on a website which interact with active directory and perform certain user operations. I want to handle the timeout situation in case of server is offline.
I am coding like this

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(this._domain,    Convert.ToInt32(this._port)));
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new  VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3; 
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic; 
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
```

Comment: I want to show a message to user in case of timeout.

Comment: Is there any kind of exception type or event handler when connection get timed out.

Comment: something like this :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net ?